# Problem with user-defined function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, t-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a user-defined function in Microsoft SQL Server, and I have a problem getting it to work correctly.

The function takes in one `NVARCHAR(MAX)` parameter that will then strip all the HTML tags from that string text and then remove all the extra white spaces via a cursor

```
CREATE FUNCTION UDF_STRIP_HTML 
     (@HTMLText NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Start INT
    DECLARE @End INT
    DECLARE @Length INT

    SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText)
    SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText))
    SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1

    WHILE @Start > 0 AND @End > 0 AND @Length > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @HTMLText = STUFF(@HTMLText, @Start, @Length, '')
        SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<', @HTMLText)
        SET @End = CHARINDEX('>', @HTMLText, CHARINDEX('<', @HTMLText))
        SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
    END

    DECLARE @WORD VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @STRING VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE AUDIT_TRAIL_CURSOR CURSOR 
    FOR 
        --Split string into individual words and ignore blanks or extra spaces
        SELECT VALUE 
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(@HTMLText, ' ') 
        WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(VALUE)) <> ''

    OPEN AUDIT_TRAIL_CURSOR

    FETCH NEXT FROM AUDIT_TRAIL_CURSOR INTO @WORD

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN 
        --Strip extra spaces from each word and add only one space after
        SET @STRING = CONCAT(@STRING, RTRIM(LTRIM(@WORD)), ' ')

        FETCH NEXT FROM AUDIT_TRAIL_CURSOR INTO @WORD
    END

    CLOSE AUDIT_TRAIL_CURSOR
    DEALLOCATE AUDIT_TRAIL_CURSOR

    RETURN @STRING
END
GO
```

The HTML stripper works fine either way, but the whitespace stripper only works if I directly pass in a hard coded string like in

This works:

```
SELECT dbo.UDF_STRIP_HTML('Some <b/>      string   with        Words.   ')
```

HTML stripper works, but whitespace stripper does not:

```
SELECT dbo.UDF_STRIP_HTML(some_column) 
FROM some_table
```

NOTE: I understand this may not be the best function, but this will be for a one time data export via query

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: It was stripping out the HTML stuff, but was not getting rid of the whitespace when referencing a column
SELECT dbo.UDF_STRIP_HTML('Hard      coded <b/>  string     works') => Returns 'Hard coded string works'
but
SELECT dbo.UDF_STRIP_HTML(column) FROM table where column is ' The Hard      coded <b/>  string     works' => returns 'Hard      coded   string     works' The whitespace is still there. It should also return 'Hard coded string works' 
@ Yitzhak Khabinsky gave me a solution that works correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML has many useful data types. One of them: `token` is very handy for your scenario.

Here is what it does:

1. All invisible TAB, Carriage Return, and Line Feed characters will be
   replaced with spaces.
2. Then leading and trailing spaces are removed from the value.
3. Further, contiguous occurrences of more than one space will be replaced with a single space.

You can replace this entire chunk:

```
DECLARE @WORD VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @STRING VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE AUDIT_TRAIL_CURSOR CURSOR 
    FOR 
    --Split string into induvidual words and ignore blanks or extra spaces
    SELECT VALUE FROM STRING_SPLIT(@HTMLText, ' ') WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(VALUE)) <> ''
    OPEN AUDIT_TRAIL_CURSOR
    FETCH NEXT FROM AUDIT_TRAIL_CURSOR INTO @WORD
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN 
        --Strip extra spaces from each word and add only one space after
        SET @STRING = CONCAT(@STRING,RTRIM(LTRIM(@WORD)),' ')
        FETCH NEXT FROM AUDIT_TRAIL_CURSOR INTO @WORD
    END
    CLOSE AUDIT_TRAIL_CURSOR
    DEALLOCATE AUDIT_TRAIL_CURSOR
    RETURN @STRING
```

With the following:

```
RETURN TRY_CAST('<r><![CDATA[' + @HTMLText + ']]></r>' AS XML).value('(/r/text())[1] cast as xs:token?','NVARCHAR(MAX)');
```

Comment: @Walt, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please up-vote my suggestion: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/38142115-sql-server-vnext-post-2019-and-nosql-functionali